# Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::where()

Tags: lumen

How can I use `where` method in `Lumen`

```
Route::get('/talent/{id}', 'TalentController@talent')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Gives me this error:

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::where()
```

Using `php 7` and `"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.5.*"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lumen uses a different router than Laravel does.

For Lumen, the regex constraint is directly in the route parameter defintion. Your code would look something like:

```
$router->get('/talent/{id:[0-9]+}', 'TalentController@talent');
```

You can read more about Lumen routing and the constraints in [the documentation here](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

Comment: @patricus how can I redirect from a post route to one of the get route? I tried to name the get route and then `return redirect()->route('foo');` from post route. But I gives "NotFoundHttpException HTTP 404 Not Found" error.